# DataTables Buttons + Column Filtering with Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I currently have a DataTable that has data download buttons in format that I'm looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
  } );
} );
```

However, I want to be able to filter columns with a dropdown menu in the footer - exactly like in the example in this link:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

The initialization code for that is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {

      initComplete: function () {
          this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
     }
  } );
} );
```

What I want is to combine these two functionalities - column filter and data download options. I've tried moving around the button and dom snippet into the code above:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
  } );
```

But I've had no luck getting it to display correctly (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

I had an engineering breakthrough and did the obvious thing, added the DOM settings before:

```
initComplete: function(){.......
```

And it worked.

Complete function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons:  [
               'copyHtml5',
               'excelHtml5',
               'csvHtml5',
               'pdfHtml5'
               ],

    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }   
 });

});
```